# How to read Config.property file save in Internal Storage manually

Tags: java, android

```
    Properties prop=new Properties();
    String filePath = getFilesDir() + "/Myfolder/" + "config.properties";
    File yourFile = new File(filePath);
    Log.d("yourFile",""+yourFile);


    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(""+yourFile);
        prop.load(in);
        String readData=prop.getProperty("database");
        Log.d("readData",readData);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**I create a config file and put it into Phone internal storage I want to read this file when i am trying to read its showing filenotfound exception how to read this file please help me.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you put the file is wrong. GetFiledirectory is the path that can not be accessed through mobile file. You should creat file in that directory first and then to write data inside it.
In other words, you are putting file in external directory and want to read it from internal directory.

Internal Storage

Files are accessible by only your app
Files are removed when your app is uninstalled
Files are always available (meaning they files will never be saved on a removable memory)

External Storage

Files are fully readable by other apps (including any variant of File Manager app, in your case)
Files aren't necessarily removed when your app is uninstalled - explained later
Files availability isn't guaranteed (can be deleted by other apps / removable memory).

You can either specified path of file in sdcard for reading file located in external directory  or  create file programmically inside internal directory following what you have done in the code.

Since you are going to create file before installing app, you can specifying path of the external storage like below

```
     String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory+  "/Myfolder/" + "config.properties";
```

Comment: i have to add first manually config file in android phone, then i have to read that file from application.